# Chrome workspace not liverefreshing static files with virtualhosts

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, less, gulp-watch, gulp-less

I am working with compiled static css files on chrome workspace.

I am using gulp-less workflow for the compilation process from less to css and live editing less files to get expected css output on chrome workspace via dev tools.

Everything worked fine and i keep getting css on dev tools when i was accessing website with localhost i.e. http://127.0.0.1/website/ but now i need to setup virtualhost to run multiple website on the same localhost server.

Added required entries in the `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName          local.website.com
  DocumentRoot        /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/
</VirtualHost>
```

as well as `etc/host` entry at the system level to map the ip to domain.

```
127.0.0.1 local.website.com
```

After moving to virtual-host http://local.website.com/, i can't get refreshed files from workspace.

What are the required configurations for setting up workspace to have better frontend workflow with virtual host?

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to regenerating same directory after clearing it.

So after removing from workspace and re-adding newlly generated files in workspace with proper permission works fine.